# How to populate Django foreign key with a temporary default value?

Tags: django

In my Django web application, when the user creates an account, a record for their account is created in the auth_user table.  Now there is one required field on the signup form, a dropdown box, that they will use to select what type of user they are.  This value is used to populate a foreign key field in a second 'profile' table.  The problem is that this profile table has numerous other required foreign key fields that also need to be populated and I need to create an initial record for the user in that profile table before they fill out the rest of their profile (and thus setting these other foreign key fields).  This may not happen for some time after the account is created. Is there a way to do this in Django?  I know you can set FK fields to `blank=True, null=True` if the field is optional, but this field really is required.  I'd like to trick Django into designating it as required with a temporary value, perhaps by adding a record like "TBD" to the table pointed to by the FK.  But putting a "TBD" field in the other table seems "unclean" to me.  How do I solve this problem?

Here is the view that creates the new user:

```
def account_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CreateAccountForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create new user object but don't save it.
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=user, type=user_form.cleaned_data['user_type'])
            return render(request, 'account/account_created.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = CreateAccountForm()
    return render(request, 'account/create_account.html', {'form': user_form})
```

Comment: Can you share the view where you construct the profile?

Comment: > This value is used to populate a foreign key field in a second 'profile' table.

Why not create a ForeignKey on the User model, and use that ForeignKey to populate the foreign key on the profile later on?
That way you can postpone the creation of the Profile to a later moment.

EDIT: Looking at your code, why can't you set the type on the user object instead of profile?

Comment: @NicoGriffioen I don't understand your suggestion. I'm not aware of a way to create a new FK in the auth_user table. It is what it is. The profile table is supposed to serve as an extension of the user table and it has a user_id field that has a one-to-one relationship with the auth_user.id field that does this. The problem, as I see it, is that I need to create it and then the user needs to fill out, including those required FK fields.

Comment: You can create a custom User model, which would allow you to add fields. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model